# Laravel: Http via auth.basic: Access user and pw after successfull login

Tags: php, laravel, http, authentication

Is there a build-in possibility in Laravel to access the username and pw that was entered previously via the browsers http-auth-basic-dialouge when using http auth basic?

I basically need the username and pw values that should be stored in the corresponding session cookie.

Comment: What is your definition of "previously" in this case and what are "the values"? Maybe you should explain a little more about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it like this now:

```
public function fn()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if(!$user || $user->getAttributeValue('additional_attribute') == 0)
    {
        return abort(401,'Sorry '.($user ? $user->name : '').', you are not authorized to access this page.');
    }

    return view('view');
}
```

Comment: @Konafets: Because i have to check the additional attribute for 1 or 0 i added to the users table. If there is a better possiblity i am glad about any help! (new at laravel)